# Why does calling a function defined in my class throw an undefined function error?

Tags: php, oop, static

This is my code:

```
<?php
class Render {
    public $dimensions =array();

    public function getDimensions($room) {
      return $this->dimensions;
    }
    public static function displayDimensions($size) {
      return $size[0] . " x " . $size[1];
    }

    public static function detailsKitchen($room) {
      return "Kitchen Dimensions: " . Render::displayDimensions(getDimensions($room));
    }
}
$room = new Render();
$room->dimensions[] = (20);
$room->dimensions[] = (10);
?>
```

This is the error:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getDimensions() in index.php:12 Stack trace: #0 6033c6f9-bc53-4bfa-9e1d-a403951652f5.php(176): Render::detailsKitchen(Object(Room)) #1 {main} thrown in index.php on line 12 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getDimensions() in index.php:12 Stack trace: #0 6033c6f9-bc53-4bfa-9e1d-a403951652f5.php(176): Render::detailsKitchen(Object(Room)) #1 {main} thrown in index.php on line 12

Comment: And `getDimensions` function is really not defined.

Comment: `getDimensions()` is not the same as `$this->getDimensions()` - which you can **not** call from a static function.

Comment: `$this` ^^^^^^^

Comment: First you need to understand why you use both static and non-static methods in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try `$room->getDimensions()`, instead of calling the method with your instance as parameter (you should change your method accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

In any language, non-static methods cannot be called from a static context. That is why it says that it is not defined. Since I think that you meant to do

```
$room->getDimensions()
```

, you should change the getDimensions() to $room->getDimensions().

Comment: You'll be suprised but in php you __can__ call non-static method using `::`

Comment: what? then how does it work then? suppose it accesses a non-static variable and you have 2 instances of the object. Now the method accesses the variable. Which of the variables is returned? the first instance or the second?

Comment: I said you __can__ run non-static method statically, but I didn't tell that it will always be a success. If a non-static method does __nothing__ with `$this` - it will work.

Comment: oh that makes sense

Comment: And since `php7` you'll get a warning for this. But in php5 it's fine.